# Framework7 - DOM Manipulation through Modals

Tags: html-framework-7

I'm building an app with FW7 but I have got an issue right now.

I created pickerModals to display data but every DOM interaction is not listened.

How can I manage to read DOM events through modals ?

code :

```
$$('.open-picker-infos').on('click', function () {

    var head = $$(this).text();

    $$.get($$(this).attr('href'), function(data){
        var target = data;


        // Check first, if we already have opened picker
        if ($$('.picker-modal.modal-in').length > 0) {
            myApp.closeModal('.picker-modal.modal-in');
        }
        myApp.pickerModal('<div class="picker-modal">'+'<div class="toolbar">' +
            '<div class="toolbar-inner">' +
            '<div class="left return_modal"><img src="img/ic_backspace_black_36px.svg" class="close-picker"></div>' +
            '<div class="middle"><span class="popup_subject">Informations pratiques</span><span class="popup_title">'+head+'</span></div>' +
            '<div class="right more-picker"><img src="img/ic_more_vert_black_36px.svg" class="more"></div>' +
            '</div></div>'+ target +'</div>')
    });
});



$$('.more-picker').on('click', function(){
    console.log('test');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Dom7 event cannot find `more-picker` class before it inserted into html.

Try to add the `more-picker click` event into the `open-picker-infos click`  event